# CMake boost also needs -lboost_* to work

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to link my code to boost, python and armadillo. Here is the CMakeLists.txt I use

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

set(EXEC_NAME phases)
set(LIBS_NAME Hamilton)
project(${EXEC_NAME})

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(LIB_HEADER point.h
               hamilton.h)
set(LIB_SOURCE  point.cpp
               hamilton.cpp)

add_library(${LIBS_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_SOURCE} ${LIB_HEADER})
add_library("${LIBS_NAME}_mod" MODULE ${LIB_SOURCE} ${LIB_HEADER})

set(HEADER_FILES point.h hamilton.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${EXEC_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${LIBS_NAME})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lboost_python")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lboost_python")

find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -larmadillo")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -larmadillo")
include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lpython")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lpython")

message(STATUS "Building in ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} ...")
```

As you can see I am adding the flag `-l...` after each library. If I remove them then I get a linker error.

Is there any nice way to avoid this?

I use intel compiler icc but also tries clang and gcc
clang doesn't need the extra `-l...` flags.

**NOTE**
Only using `target_link_libraries` without the `CMAKE_xxx_flags` gives me a linker error. That is why I am asking this question.

I have cmake 3.3, boost 1.59 with boost-python and armadillo installed using homebrew

**Update**

The error I get is

```
Reaping winning child 0x7fa188492f80 PID 47863 
Live child 0x7fa188492f80 (libHamilton.dylib) PID 47864 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN5boost6python15instance_holder10deallocateEP7_objectPv", referenced from:  
__ZN5boost6python7objects11make_holderILi3EE5applyINS1_12value_holderI8Hami    ltonEENS_3mpl7vector3IKdKmSB_EEE7executeEP7_objectdmm in hamilton.cpp.o
```

which is from linking to boost libraries.

Outputting the content of `Boost_LIBRARIES` gives me

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
```

on the other hand `Boost_python_LIBRARY` returns empty string

Comment: what version of cmake do you use?

Comment: I have cmake 3.3 installed using homebrew

Comment: What error you are getting, which library is missing? Also try to link with verbose enabled and see what libraries are specified there

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [FindBoost doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html)

```
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

need to be used, remove

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lboost_python")
```

etc

Check content of `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable:

```
 message( "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}" )
```

You may try to use `Boost_python_LIBRARY` variable instead, also `Boost_python_LIBRARY_DEBUG` or `Boost_python_LIBRARY_RELEASE` may work, in this case most probably your boost installation is somehow broken or at least not the way as expected by cmake module.

Update: your error shows that you have issue linking with multythread or shared  version of boost_python. You can fix it by specifying:

```
set( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF )
```

or

```
set( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON )
```

before `find_package` or find the cause of that linking error.

Comment: I have already said that only using `target_link_libraries` didn't work for me. That is why I added `CMAKE_xxx_FLAGS`.

Comment: In which particular case it does not work? Most probably you are using wrong variable in `target_link_libraries` somewhere

Comment: I have the exact same line as `target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` in my code. If I remove the two lines under it, i get the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question again to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @Ashkan unfortunately there are way to many moving parts, you need to check which library is linked when you specify -lboost_python vs -lboost_python-mt and so on. Looks like you have different boost libraries installed on your system, and you compile and link with different ones.